# Is there any JavaScript IDE that's able to show all used objects fields and methods in IntelliSense?

Tags: javascript, ide, javascript-intellisense

For example, I am using Google Maps API and I want to see all possible fields and methods.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ge;
google.load("earth", "1");
```

If I type `google.` I want to see every available functions and fields

For now I use Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and it shows only base methods available for all objects like toString().

Comment: Yup I have also been searching for this. I believe proper support like for example what Java has is still missing from IDE's. P.S: I believe Netbeans and Aptana had it, but still pretty basic compared to like Java.

Comment: Aptana is some weird thing :P when i type google. it show me everything, aside of what fields and functions google object is really has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge not yet, but you can use this simple code to "print" all that's in an object.
It is crude but it works :)

```
// Obj.keys(); strict
// Object.getOwnPropertyNames( obj ) strict
get_keys = function get_keys (obj) {    // all inhereted keys

    var keys = [], key;

    for(key in obj)
    {
        //if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {keys.push(key);}
        keys.push(key);
    }
    obj = key = null;
    return keys;
};
stringify_object = function stringify_object(obj){

    var keys = get_keys(obj),
    str = '',
    i, len = keys.length;

    for(i=0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        str += i + ": " +keys[i] + ' : ' + obj['"'+keys[i]+'"'] +'\n\n';
    }

obj = keys = i = len = null;
    return str;
};
```

Comment: this is cool, but it same as reading docs :P it's better to have it in IntelliSense